# ion auth login taking very long time to load

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, ion-auth

I am using the ion-auth plugin with CodeIgnitor login and signup authentication on my website. It all works correctly but the login takes over 20 seconds to authenticate and reload the page. These are my configuration options, not sure if they directly impact load time.

```
$config['hash_method']    = 'bcrypt';   // sha1 or bcrypt, bcrypt is     STRONGLY recommended
$config['default_rounds'] = 8;      // This does not apply if random_rounds is set to true
$config['random_rounds']  = TRUE;
$config['min_rounds']     = 13;
$config['max_rounds']     = 16;
$config['salt_prefix']    = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<') ? '$2a$' : '$2y$';
```

I am hosting the website on hostgator.

How can I speed up load time?